# Upload a file to Drupal server from (external) desktop client application (in c#)

Tags: files

I have an application written in Winform (dotNet) and I would like it to Upload File to Drupal 7. 
I'm newbie in Drupal. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create something with the Services module. The services module gives you an easy way to add REST / XMLRPC services to your drupal site. http://drupal.org/project/services

See also the documentation: http://drupal.org/node/736522

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 6 you've the built-in module Blog Api that fellows XML-RPC Blogging Standards. For Drupal 7 is now a contributed module that you can find easily [here](http://drupal.org/project/blogapi).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot transfer files using a web service. I had tried it but was not able to do it.

What you have to do is create a simple MENU_CALLBACK using hook_menu(). Something like this,

```
function my_module_menu(){
 $items['upload'] = array(
    'title'             => 'Transferfile',
    'description'       => 'Allows client to upload.',
    'access arguments'  => array('access content'),   //or whatever else you want to check
    'access callback'   => 'user_access',
    'page callback'     => 'upload',
    'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );
  return $items;    
 }


function upload(){

//use file_move() api here and take the details about the uploaded file from $_FILES.

}
```

Thats it on server side.

On the client end you will want to hit the menu callback and pass on your file. A simple Html code to simulate the transfer will be following.

```
<html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://mydomain.com/upload" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</html>
```

You will get the details of the uploded file in the $_FILES array. the name o fthe key here will be same as the name of your file input element, in our case it will be "uploadedfile".

This should work, give it a try. :)